# SSRS count duplicate IDs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to count the number of duplicates in SSRS. So for example if an ID appears more than twice count the number of ID's that do this. For example

ID
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
4

So in this example only 1 and 3 appear more than twice so the expected result would be 2

I have tried different background VB code to work but it doesn't seem to work.

SUM(IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!LearnerID.Value))>1,1,0).

Comment: I would recommend you describe the context of how you want to display this data and expected output.

Comment: I want to be able to count the number of times an ID appears more than once.

Comment: In what? A table? A chart? A text field? Is this for every ID or specific IDs? Can you do it in a query? Is it cheating to ask someone to do your homework on Stackoverflow?

Comment: in a table. every ID. Then why even respond? I am just asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this in SSRS.

1. Add a row number to your dataset that will count the number of rows for each ID. It would look something like this:

   `ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) as RN`
2. Add a calculated field to your dataset that will check which IDs went over 2 like this:

   `=IIf(Fields!RN.Value > 2, Fields!ID.Value, Nothing)`
3. Count the distinct IDs that met this requirement anywhere in your report using an expression like this:

   `=CountDistinct(Fields!MoreThanTwo.Value, "DataSet1")`

The `CountDistinct` function here has its scope overwritten to cover the entire dataset. You can remove that or change it depending on where it is in the report.

Comment: Thanks for this the only issue is because we are a school we aren't able to add a row number.

Comment: I'm confused, you can't use SQL? How are you getting data into the report?